# How to preserve data in UITableview between launches

Tags: ios, uitableview, chat

I'm building a chat app. Now I know how to create a chat session, but I want to know how to preserve the data of chat history between launches.

Anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out a data model that can be expressed as a .plist (dictionary, array, string, number, data, date) and keep it in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm not sure is it a good idea to store such amount data in NSUserDefault ?

Comment: I don't think the amount really matters. A file is a file is a file; if you save it in NSUserDefaults or in a CoreData file or in a plist file elsewhere, it's all the same amount of data. The objection would be that NSUserDefaults are for preferences, whereas this is state. But I don't think there's any need to be a strict purist about this. I often keep state-related data in NSUserDefaults and no Thought Police have come after me... :)

Comment: I like this answer no to be strict!

Comment: NSUserDefaults will get you started. Once you have an NSUserDefaults data saving-and-restore strategy, you can always change your mind and save into a file instead, with very little change of code.

Answer (score 1):

Use Core Data to mimic the data model coming in through the chat, you can then store all chat objects in core data as they are created and load them from core data on app launch.